What determines which of the two hyd. systems (A and B) available for the primary flight controls is used in manual flight ? (B737)
With CMD A engaged, sys A will be used and with CMD B engaged, then it will be system B. But what exactly determines the hydraulic source used during manual flight (pressure available, system load…)?

During manual flight with hydraulic pressure available, is your question?

That is not the way it works. The two systems operate all the major controls independently so that either system can be used to safely control the aircraft. As you mentioned, the autopilot A for example controls the aircraft by operating on hydraulic system A, and autopilot B operates on hydraulic system B. Unless one system has failed, the pilots manual controls operate on both systems simultaneously.

So this means that both are always used together when flying manually, do you have a reliable source to read more about this operation and the PCU’s operation in general ? Thank you for your information !

@dnblkj - If you google "737 FCOM" you will find the flight crew operations manual is available from many sources.

I think you are confusing the hydraulic power control units (PCUs) which move the control surfaces with the hydraulic servos for the autopilot.
The 737 uses conventional flight controls with steel cables connecting the yokes and rudder pedals to the hydraulic PCUs, which use hydraulic pressure to move the actual flight control surface. Both systems A and B are used for this:

The primary flight control system uses conventional control wheel, column and
pedals linked mechanically to hydraulic power control units which command the
primary flight control surfaces; ailerons, elevators and rudder. The flight controls
are powered by redundant hydraulic sources; system A and system B. Either
hydraulic system can operate all primary flight controls.

(Boeing 737 NG FCOMv2 - 9.20.1 Flight Controls - System Description)
The autopilot also uses hydraulic pressure to operate its servos. But these are not directly connected to the control surfaces. Instead, the servos operate on the steel cables connecting the yokes and the PCUs. This also results in movement of the yokes as the autopilot inputs commands.

The AFDS is a dual system consisting of two individual flight control computers
(FCCs) and a single mode control panel.
The two FCCs are identified as A and B. For A/P operation, they send control
commands to their respective pitch and roll hydraulic servos, which operate the
flight controls through two separate hydraulic systems.

(Boeing 737 NG FCOMv2 - 4.20.1 Automatic Flight - System Description)
As you can see in the following picture and table, autopilot A uses hydraulic system A for its servos and B uses B. But the actual control surfaces are using both hydraulic systems:

Hydraulic Power Distribution Schematic

A and B Hydraulic Systems
Components powered by hydraulic systems A and B are:



System A
System B




ailerons
ailerons


rudder
rudder


elevator and elevator feel
elevator and elevator feel


flight spoilers (two on each wing)
flight spoilers (two on each wing)


ground spoilers
leading edge flaps and slats


alternate brakes
normal brakes


No. 1 thrust reverser
No. 2 thrust reverser


autopilot A
autopilot B


normal nose wheel steering
alternate nose wheel steering


landing gear
landing gear transfer unit.


power transfer unit (PTU)
autoslats



yaw damper



trailing edge flaps




(Boeing 737 NG FCOMv2 - 13.20.1 Hydraulics - System Description)
